# What's the difference between conda skeleton and conda install?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

Following [this tutorial](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/conda-data-science/) `conda skeleton` should be used for installing non `r-essential` R packages. however this hasn't worked for me. However after searching online [this post](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4355) suggests to use `conda install -c r r-packagename` which worked for me. So what is the difference between `conda skeketon` and `conda install`?

Comment: OK. I'm not a `conda` user and all I did was read the cited page and make analogies with the equivalent process in R.

Answer (score 1):

The `skeleton` command is used to jump-start the building of your own package. The `install` command is for installing someone else's package (or one that you previously finished.)